# Edible Plants for Rockery

Tags: dryness, rock-gardening

So in my new allotment, I have a large mound (approx 2.5m diameter, 1m high) of turf sods which has over time become a solid hill of dry, reasonably fine soil with grass and weeds covering it. It's taking up good space on the allotment, so I wanted to see if I can make it worthwhile otherwise I will just level it.

It's oval shaped, with oval aligned East/West facing so there is good slope exposed to sun. As it is so raised, it's quite dry from sun and wind. Since it's sunny and dry, I was thinking perhaps I could create a rockery (that and the allotment has more flint than soil) but I'm not sure what edible plants I could grow on it.

What kind of edible, and worth eating, plants (veg, fruit or herbs) would grow well in these conditions, or is any suggestion going to be a compromise and leveling it out always the better option? I'm guessing herbs like rosemary, lavender?

Thoughts?

EDIT: There is another hidden benefit in that the mound is also partially hollow (people stealing the good, sifted soil). The hollow section could be a great place to grow mushrooms.

Comment: I'd recommend you dig that heap into your allotment soil - composted down turves make nutrient rich compost, brilliant for your soil generally.

Comment: Fair enough, perhaps that would be best. More digging then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comment, suggest you dig it into your allotment - the reason people are taking it is because they know it's valuable either as an addition to making potting compost, or simply using it to add to their own plots. Paradoxically, it wouldn't be great for growing lavender or rosemary - most herb type plants prefer poorer, less nutrient rich soil conditions. It does mean more digging, yes - but you were probably going to do that anyway in preparation for winter, either sowing winter crops or rough digging to allow the frost to get at the clods of soil.